# redirecting url: "xyz" in eventsource of fullcalendar to and action class

Tags: jquery, struts2, fullcalendar

I am a newbie in web app development, currently I am assigned a web app at work, where I need to implement full calendar using struts2 java, I have displayed it , but I am unable to redirect it to an action class which takes data from mySQL and displays it. Please give me pointers on how to do it, I am trying this for 8 days now , but still no luck.

Thanks!!!

code added:

I know that for java/servlet syntax for event source for getting json feeds was:

```
eventSources: [{
            url: '/mailexample/calendarevents',
            type: 'GET',
             dataType: 'json',
          }]
```

as of now i have tried:

```
url: 'calanderevents.action',
type: 'GET',
 dataType: 'json',
```

or

```
 url action: 'calendarevents',
    type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'json',
```

or

```
url: 'calendarevents',  
// where calendar events maps to an action class
        type: 'GET',
         dataType: 'json',
```

non of all this seem to work.please help.

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps you want to post the code you have currently and describe what isn't working about it?

Comment: @StevenBenitez: I have added those I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this... Try it

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: function(start, end, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'calanderevents.action',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
            start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
            end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000)
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var events = [];
            // logic to get each item from data and push it in events array
            callback(events);
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: @K D : I tried but no action is being called, its treating calendar events.action as a url (http://localhost:8080/ProjectX/calendar.action?start=1363845600&end=1363932000)    and my console shows now action being called. :(

Comment: Tell me your url from which you are accessing event data.. send me the entire path of it

Comment: Hi Now I can see json-events being called but they are not being displayed on my calendar.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/ProjectX/json-events.php?start=1361689200&end=1365318000&_=1363989086105     this is what is being called, but there is no errors and no results.